# Can we add Marketo form in amp page?

Tags: amp-html, marketo

I want to add a `Marketo` form in AMP page. Is there any way to add `Marketo` form in Google AMP page?

Answer (score 0):

It says from this [thread](https://nation.marketo.com/message/177416-marketo-munchkin-tracking-amp-web-pages) that it is possible to use a pluggable analytics module from AMP `<amp-analytics>`.

But there will be a problem when embedding marketo form to an AMP page because AMP is a static renderer. The stats from your application may be innacurate because it goes "static first". You can also follow this link for the discussion about [Conflict of Marketo with Google AMP](https://nation.marketo.com/message/125150).